# ASP.NET: How to Update String data in Web Api Controller using Jquery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

Hei everyone. i have project to make communication between my website and my application using web api. i have success to get data from api controller in my application and browser (via url). but i can't update the data in my website. for example: i write a text on input box and click the write button. when i click read button the data not change.

the data i want to update is string data.
here is my code

Web Api with read/write template

```
public class ActionController : ApiController
    {
        public string text1 = "Read Data Success";
        // GET: api/Action
        public string Get()
        {          
            return text1;
        }

        // GET: api/Action/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {          
            return "value" + id;
        }

        // POST: api/Action
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            text1 = value;
        }

        // PUT: api/Action/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {

        }

        // DELETE: api/Action/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {

        }
    }
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Server Manager</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <script src="Scripts/Action.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="write" />
        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="read" />
        <input id="TextIn1" type="text" />
        <p id="text1">Text 1</p>              

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {
        var TextIn = $("#TextIn1").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api/Action',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: TextIn,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Writed " + response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }

        });
        console.log("write complete");
    });
    $("#Button2").click(function () {     

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/Action',             
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $("#text1").text("Get " + data);
            },
            error: function (responese) {
                alert(responese.responseText);

            }  
        });  
    console.log("read complete");
});

});
```

i know my code looks weird or ambiguous. because this is my first time in web programming

Comment: text1 variable is initialized with value "Read Data Success" on every request, because it's a variable of class, and class is created every time you send request

Comment: so this variable can't be change?

Comment: try public  static string text1

Comment: its work but i got NULL data when read the string

Comment: its fixed now. i follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543912/passing-object-from-jquery-ajax-to-webapi-results-to-null

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `[FromBody]` attribute from the `Post` method.

Comment: it's not working. i got error message
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

Answer (score 0):

this is never going to work.

WebAPI is stateless, this means that requests are independent and separate and there is no state maintained between requests.

what you are doing is this:

- send POST request, `text1` gets initialized and updated correctly
- send GET request, `text1` is initialized again with the default value and returned as such.

Typically when you POST something, some data will be created / updated in a database, for example.

a GET request comes in, goes to the db and gets the data as it is, after the change.

If you want to see changes happening, then you can do something else, update a text file on disk for example and when you issue the GET request then you read from the same file. You will then see the changes properly. Point is, use something real for storage and understand what stateless means for an API.